# Bluetooth Data Connectivity issue

Tags: bluetooth, module

I am using an [RN42-I/RM](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/268/RN42_RN42N_Class_2_Bluetooth_Module_with_EDR_Suppo-2998843.pdf) Bluetooth Module, ADS1298IPAG and dsPIC33EP256MC202 206 IC 16 Bit Micro Controller & Digital Controller.

The problem I am facing is initially the RN42 Bluetooth module will pair with a mobile device & android app used for analyzing ECG waveforms.

After a few days or months, the RN42 Bluetooth stops sending 3.3 V (Pin No 19) (GPIO 2) to dsPIC33EP256MC206 IC (Pin No 30)(AN15/RP195/RE15).
Though their supply voltage is present at Pin No 11 and also at Pin No 13,14 3.3V is present in RN42.

The baud rate of RN42 Bluetooth is set to 460K.

Comment: GPIO2 signals the connection status (high when connected, low otherwise). Have you tried to unpair-pair the Bluetooth device anew?

Comment: please add a specific, answerable question to your post